# Reviewing your changes since a particular review on github

Tags: github

I pushed a PR.

A reviewer asked for changes.

I make changes and push again.

I would like to be able to see **only my new changes** since his review on github to make sure I did what I was supposed to do. 
Atm I can't because I haven't reviewed it yet (option disabled). Only the reviewer can click on it:

[image]

Is there a way to view it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is finding out the commit when the review took place and then compare it to your commit by manually editing the url and adding 2 dots between commit ids, like this
https://github.com/user/repo/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6f

source: https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparing-commits

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see individual commits from "Commits" tab.[image]

Comment: yes, but how does that help me? it shows only the difference to the previous commit, not to the review...